# Math.abs(element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight - element.scrollTop) < 1;

Tags: javascript, scroll

I came across a piece of code on the MDN documentation used to determine if the scrollbar has reached the bottom. The code is as follows:

```
Math.abs(element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight - element.scrollTop) < 1
```

I have a question about this code. Why is the Math.abs API used here? Under normal circumstances, scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollTop cannot be negative."

I have searched the internet and have not found a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Please add the link to the source of that information?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled: _"scrollTop is a non-rounded number, while scrollHeight and clientHeight are rounded"_ - so under the right circumstances, where the latter two got rounded, but the former one still might have decimals, you _might_ get a negative value, I suppose.